# Any way to limit which pools can contribute to an Artifact feed?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Given an Azure Artifacts Feed named 'deployables' (available to the Organization as a whole) and two Azure Pipelines agent pools (named 'Corporate' and 'Testing').

Is there a way to give the Corporate agent pool contributor access to the 'deployables' Artifacts feed but not to the 'Testing' pool?

Comment: yes you can limit that by setting up security-groups and assigning them as users for the pools

Comment: Hi,@David Does your puzzle solved now? Does my answer give you any help? If convenient, you can share the latest status of this issue with us.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to give the Corporate agent pool contributor access to
>   the 'deployables' Artifacts feed but not to the 'Testing' pool?

I'm afraid Azure Devops does not provide the direct feature that agent pool can be limited to access Artifacts.

But as workaround, you can through specify the permission of user/group to achieve this indirectly. For instance, there is a `group A` which have access permission of `Artifacts Feed 'deployables'`. Give this group the access permission of `'Corporate' pool`, BUT denyied in `'Testing' pool`.